# How to create this awesome transformation animations from manim python math animation library in blender?

Tags: animation, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, bezier-curves, transforms

[image]

### It is the output of following python script

```py
class test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("some text.")
        text1 = Text("another text.")
        text2 = Text("its some text.")
        rect = Rectangle()
        circle = Circle()
        text.to_edge(UP)
        text1.move_to(text.get_corner(LEFT+DOWN)-np.array([text1.get_corner(LEFT+UP)]))
        text2.move_to(text1.get_corner(LEFT+DOWN)-np.array([text2.get_corner(LEFT+UP)]))
        rect.next_to(text1,DOWN)
        circle.next_to(rect,RIGHT)
        self.add(text)
        self.play(Transform(text,text1))
        self.play(Transform(text, text2))
        self.play(Transform(text, VGroup(rect,circle)))
        self.wait()
```

- In the first animation, see how 'o' from text "some" just move to "o" in text "another" and other characters are transforming to other characters.
- In the second animation, see how "text" just moves a little bit.

[manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) is creating those elements as svg images with line paths.
After that it creates each character as sub element for performing transformations.

### How can we create this awesome transformation animations in blender in such a way that we can use those transformations for other objects.?

Comment: probably not, at least not easily, as 3d shapes are much more complex to work with than 2d vector graphics

Comment: may be somehow with python script.